# Term for a leaf in a family tree

Tags: genetics

Imagine a family pedigree.

Mathematically it is a graph, which consists of nodes and edges.
Nodes being family members, and edges - their relationships.

In a clinical setting, what is the proper term for the nodes? Would they be called 'leafs'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in a pedigree, *[Standardized Human Pedigree Nomenclature: Update and Assessment of the Recommendations of the National Society of Genetic Counselors](http://geneticcounselingtoolkit.com/cases/pedigree/Bennett%20JGC%202008%20-%20Standardized%20Human%20Pedigree%20Nomenclature%20-%20Update%20and%20Assessment%20of%20the%20Recommendations%20of%20the%20National%20Society%20of%20Genetic%20Counselors.pdf)* notes that these "nodes" in the pedigree are the "individual symbol" denoting individuals. Although, when you read it, you'd read "Male," "Female," "Gender Unspecified," etc. instead of individual symbol.